# Detect a button from a custom cell and change the properties

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I have a table where there is a button into a custom cell. When I press this button, it calls a method that detects the button using this code:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"row"] intValue] inSection: 0];
PlaceRoomCustomCell *cell = (PlaceRoomCustomCell*)[self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
for (UIView *view in  cell.contentView.subviews){
    if (view.tag == 1) {
        for (UIView *subview in  view.subviews){
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
                  [(UIButton *)subview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeRoomTableCellLikeButtonRedIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                  [(UIButton *)subview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeRoomTableCellLikeButtonRedIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                  [(UIButton *)subview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeRoomTableCellLikeButtonRedIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

                  NSLog(@"tag %i",subview.tag); //correct
             }
         }
      }
}
```

the tag is correct, but the image is not changed.

I can't use the id sender of button directly, or rather, I prefer not to use it.

the code seems correct

thank you!

Comment: Can you make sure the indexPath is correct? How about setting the button you want to change as a property in the PlaceRoomCustomCell class?

Comment: the indexpath is correct: it is the indexpath.row.

Comment: I meant to say: the tag is the indexpath.row

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when any UI object sends an action to your controller, the method is passed the `sender`, can you not use this?

e.g. the definition of the method where that code above sits might be something like:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

where `sender` should be the button.
Although I have a sneaky suspicion that we're missing some other vital information in the question, since you're using NSNotifications...

Comment: I use another asynchronous method that calls after this. I do not call this method directly